# Python - Postgresql Invalid Byte Sequence for varchar - Weird Behavior

Tags: python, postgresql

I have written a script that uses the python threading function. I think the problem has something to do with the threading because when I run the query from outside of the worker thread, it works fine. I am trying to insert some stuff into the database but ran into some REALLY funky behavior.

Let me simplify:

Running this works:

```
cmd = "INSERT INTO cstanley_temp (device, host, ux, units) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);"
data = ("solaris-cdc", resultHOST[0], "UX10", 1,)
sql.execute(cmd, data)
```

Running this does not work:

```
cmd = "INSERT INTO cstanley_temp (device, host, ux, units) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);"
data = ("solaris-cdc", resultHOST[0], "sdsdsdsdsdsd", 1,)
sql.execute(cmd, data)
```

Here are the field types:
`device` = varchar
`host` = varchar
`ux` = varchar
`units` = int

This is the error I am receiving:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/cstanley/scripts/vip/sun_audit.py", line 37, in workon
    sql.execute(cmd, data)
DataError: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x86
HINT:  This error can also happen if the byte sequence does not match the encoding expected by the server, which is controlled by "client_encoding".

Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/cstanley/scripts/vip/sun_audit.py", line 37, in workon
    sql.execute(cmd, data)
InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

Here is the full code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
import sys, os, string, threading
import paramiko
import psycopg2
import time

#paramiko.util.log_to_file("sun_audit.log")

getCPU = "/usr/sbin/psrinfo -p"
getMEM = "/usr/sbin/prtconf | grep \"Memory\" | awk '{ print $3 }'"
getHOST = "hostname"

class bcolors:
    MAGENTA = '\033[95m'
    YELLOW = '\033[93m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'

def workon(host,sql):

    #Connect to each host
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("/home/cstanley/scripts/vip/cstanley")
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(host, username='cstanley', pkey=key)

    #Run Commands
    stdinHOST, stdoutHOST, stderrHOST = ssh.exec_command(getHOST)
    stdinCPU, stdoutCPU, stderrCPU = ssh.exec_command(getCPU)
    stdinMEM, stdoutMEM, stderrMEM = ssh.exec_command(getMEM)

    with threading.Lock():

        resultHOST = stdoutHOST.readlines()
        #print "{0} {0} UX10 1".format(resultHOST[0].rstrip())
        cmd = "INSERT INTO cstanley_temp (device, host, ux, units) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);"
        data = ("solaris-cdc", resultHOST[0], "sdsdsdsdsdsd", 1,)
        sql.execute(cmd, data)

        resultCPU = stdoutCPU.readlines()
        ux40 = (int(resultCPU[0].rstrip()) - 1)
        if ux40 != 0:
            #print "{0} {0} UX40 {1}".format(resultHOST[0].rstrip(),ux40)
            cmd = "INSERT INTO cstanley_temp (device, host, ux, units) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);"
            data = ("solaris-cdc", resultHOST[0], "UX40", ux40,)
            sql.execute(cmd, data)

        resultMEM = stdoutMEM.readlines()
        ux30 = (int(resultMEM[0].rstrip()) / 1024 - 2) / 2
        #print "{0} {0} UX30 {1}".format(resultHOST[0].rstrip(),ux30)
        cmd = "INSERT INTO cstanley_temp (device, host, ux, units) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);"
        data = ("solaris-cdc", resultHOST[0], "UX30", ux30,)
        sql.execute(cmd, data)

        ssh.close()

def main():

    #date = (time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

    #Define our connection string
    conn_string = "host='REMOVED' dbname='REMOVED' user='REMOVED' password='REMOVED' connect_timeout=3"

    # print the connection string we will use to connect
    #print bcolors.MAGENTA + 'Connecting to database\n    ->%s' % (conn_string) + bcolors.ENDC + "\n"

    # get a connection, if a connect cannot be made an exception will be raised here
    conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)

    # conn.cursor will return a cursor object, you can use this cursor to perform queries
    sql = conn.cursor()
    print bcolors.YELLOW + "Inserting Solaris information into table.\n" + bcolors.ENDC

    with open('/home/cstanley/scripts/vip/sun_ip') as ip:
        hosts = ip.read().splitlines()

    threads = []
    for h in hosts:
        t = threading.Thread(target=workon, args=(h,sql,))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)
    for t in threads:
        t.join()

    conn.commit()
    sql.close()
    conn.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Trying to figure out what is going on here. Why does it work when I input `UX10` but not when I input `sdsdsdsdsdsd`? I have even tried replacing it with `solaris-cdc` just like it is in the first part of the query, but that also fails. What in the world is going on!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be saying: you're trying to insert some Python 2 `str`s with binary into a varchar column, when PostgreSQL was expecting that proper UTF-8 encoded unicode be given. Either it comes from the `resultHOST[0]` intermittently, or perhaps you've got some invisible control character in your code in the `"sdsdsdsdsdsd"` string:

```
>>> print u"here be ma\x86gic"
here be magic
```

However the real reason might be that according to [psycopg2 documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html),

> Cursors are not thread safe: a multithread application can create many cursors from the same connection and should use each cursor from a single thread. See [Thread and process safety](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#thread-safety) for details.

Thus you should create a new cursor on each thread. Instead of passing the `sql` as an argument to `workon`, just create a new cursor within the `workon` method with the statement

```
sql = conn.cursor()
```

Also, there shouldn't be any need for locking, as using a single connection with multiple cursors is thread-safe as is.

Comment: How is "UX10" normal while "sdsdsdsdsd" is not? Also, how is "solaris-cdc" normal on one field, while the other field "solaris-cdc" does not work? Both fields are the exact same type. Obviously that is the problem, but what is the solution? It appears to me that the threading is somehow putting binary data where it should not. Do you see that running two EXACT queries cause different problems when the field is "UX10" vs "sdsdsdsdsd" - The problem is obvious, yes postgres is expecting UTF-8 and receiving something else. That's not my question - my question is why is my script sending binary.

Comment: I typed in sdsdsdsdsd manually - and when changing it back to `UX10` it works. So, of it was comming from resultHOST[0] I would expect it to still throw an error when the field has been changed back to `UX10`

Comment: Can you get a MVCE of this? The question does not certainly have a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - far from it

Comment: The problem is with how the code stands - as is. When I tried making a MVCE (stripping out as much as I could) it works. Maybe it has something to do with the results it is getting from the connection to the servers (over ssh). I am not a developer by any means so my code is going to be poorly written. I wrote the SQL statements to a file before executing and got what I expected:

`INSERT INTO cstanley_temp (device, host, ux, units) VALUES (solaris-cdc, REMOVED
, solaris-cdc, 1);INSERT INTO cstanley_temp (device, host, ux, units) VALUES (solaris-cdc, REMOVED
, solaris-cdc, 1);`

Comment: Or it can have something to do with sharing a single cursor with separate threads. Can you replicate it if you have only *1* thread running. BTW, `with threading.Lock():` is not correct either - it creates a new lock, locks it (succeeds immediately since this is the only place it is ever seen), then throws it away

Comment: Yes, I just now tested - running it with one thread works with no error. Can you please elaborate? I am very new to threading. I took the `with threading.Lock()` from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485428/creating-multiple-ssh-connections-at-a-time-using-paramiko

Comment: Sorry - running it with only 1 host works - changing thread to 1 still gives errors

Comment: That code creates only one lock, in the beginning, and locks it repeatedly. You're supposed to try to hold the same lock in all threads in turns - now in each thread each pass goes to shop to buy a new lock that it holds, until throw it away at the end of `with`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105604/discussion-between-christopher-stanley-and-antti-haapala).