# Multiple concurrent SFTP connections in python

Tags: python, multithreading, ssh, sftp

My goal is to concurrently fetch files from multiple servers including multiple files from the same server. I am given a dict of file paths to fetch.

I'm thinking of something like this: [paramiko multi ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485428/creating-multiple-ssh-connections-at-a-time-using-paramiko) but with SFTP.

I have a list of opened `pysftp.Connection` objects. I can reuse these connection handles, so at least if I need to interact with the same server, the initialization process is skipped. I've been using this without errors. When I use `threading` for invoking the function that fetches the files however, it stops working, because multiple threads are trying to take over the same SFTP connection which is not supported by `pysftp`.

Do you know any workaround for this?

Comment: Have you tried multiprocessing, i.e. https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor-example

Comment: I cannot use multiprocessing because this is a daemon which can't fork processes. This is a self-defense of the multiprocessing library to prevent forked processes becoming zombies. Also, I need the shared memory space in which the SFTP connection objects are in. I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: You have multiple dictionaries with the same key?  How can you be given {'1.1.1.1':..., '1.1.1.1'}?  If you reorganize your data so that you have only one key per connection, with a list of file names, then it's simple - run your threading on each connection, and have each thread loop over getting each file in the list.

Comment: Okay. I was making up that example fast. I'll try that, sounds like a good idea

Comment: did you get it, Do you have your code