# simulating the clients using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, sockets

I have a client program but it generates only one client but i would like to simulate multiple clients like more than 100 to 1000 at least different ports using python. I am not sure how to do it. Please give an idea.

Update:
I tried use localhost for testing and i could send requests from different port. But the loop i tried for 100 clients doesn't seem to work. Any idea whats wrong?

```
def con_server(Host,port):
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
    host='localhost'
    for p in range(5000,5100):  -> I always get 5099 port connection in server side.
    por =p
    ad=(host,por)
    sock.bind(ad)
    address=(Host,port)
    sock.sendto("connection".encode(),address)
    data,server=sock.recvfrom(4096)
    data=data.decode()
    print('Client:' +data)


if __name__=="__main__":
    t2=threading.Thread(target=con_server,name='con_servr',args=("192.168.1.cc,4242))
    t2.start()
    t2.join()
```

I would like to simulate more clients from one machine.

Edited:

```
import socket
import select
def create_socket(UDP_PORT):
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind(("localhost",UDP_PORT))
    return server_socket
def main():
    read_list=[]
    for UDP_PORT in range(5000,5010):
        read_list.append(create_socket(UDP_PORT))
    while True:
        server_socket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        host="localhost"
        port=4242
        address=(host,port)
        server_socket.sendto("connection".encode(), address)
        data, server = server_socket.recvfrom(4096)
        data = data.decode()
        print('Client:' + data)


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

I tried to modify the code but the problem is that server accepts infinite number of ports. But i wanted it to accept only from 5000 to 5010. Can someone tell me whats wrong with my code.

Comment: Create multiple clients instead of only one. You can use list to store them. `Clients = []` then `Clients.append(C);`

Comment: refer this example also. It worked for me  https://stackoverflow.com/a/3485469/11548820

Comment: @RA i would like to have more than 1000 clients for testing the server program. So is there a way ?

Comment: @udit kanotra the example is good but i have to add 1000 clients and i cant manually type it.

Comment: @KSp Why don't you simply use a loop to generate them?

Comment: @RA Can you provide some code so it would be more clear. Thanks

Comment: @RA i tried the way you said but please check my updated answer